# Solving system of equations for variable

Tags: equation-solving

I'm new to mathematica and trying to use it solve this system

`Solve[{x + z == (y (x + z))/(x + y + z),  x + y == (z (x + y))/(x + y + z),  y + z == (x (y + z))/(x + y + z)}, {x, y, z}]`

But I get nothing out of it

how can I solve for x= y= z= (in relation to the other variables)?

Comment: Looks like **no** solution, try: `Reduce[{x + z == (y (x + z))/(x + y + z), 
  x + y == (z (x + y))/(x + y + z), 
  y + z == (x (y + z))/(x + y + z)}, {x, y, z}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: If Solve returns an empty list, it means that there is no general solution for any value of the parameters. You have no parameters, so there is no solution. If Reduce returns empty, it means that there is not even a solution for special values of the parameters.